# general questions regarding react native. props and style

Tags: javascript, react-native, styles, jsx, react-props

I was tasked with making some tweaks on a react native app. while it's not my skill there is no one available to work on this so I am stuck with it. for the most part I was able to make the edits needed, however I have few questions about the code if anyone can help me understand better.

1 - what is the difference between

```
       color={Colors.myColorGold}
       color: Colors.myColorGold
```

2 - if I want to use the predefined style but change one parameter like color, or font size how can I do it while keeping the rest of the parameters

```
<Text style={{ color: Colors.ochsnerGold, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
      <Text style={styles.emphasized}>{alert.SensorType}</Text>
```

3 - 
what is the differance between the two below

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPreferences');
    this.navigate('NotificationPreferences')
```

4 - and lastly, I wanted to change the color of the placeholder, I have tried everything without success, below is the code and all the things I tried.

```
const ItemPicker = ({itemOptions, handleChangeitem, selectedItemID}) => {
  return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
      <RNPickerSelect
          placeholder={{label: 'Select an item', value: null, placeholderTextColor: Colors.myGold}}
          placeholderTextColor={Colors.myGold} //tried this
          items={itemOptions}
          onValueChange={handleChangeItem}
          style={{inputIOS: styles.inputIOS, inputAndroid: styles.inputAndroid, Color: Colors.myGold}} //tried this
          value={selectedItemID}
          textColor={Colors.myGold} //tried this
      />
  ) : (
      <Picker
          selectedValue={selectedItemID}
          style={styles.inputAndroid}
          onValueChange={handleChangeItem}
          textColor={Colors.myGold} //tried this
          Color={Colors.myGold} //tried this

      >
        <Picker.Item  label="Select a Item" value="null" textColor={Colors.myGold} Color={Colors.myGold}/> //tried this
        {
          itemOptions.map((item) => (
              <Picker.Item key={item.value} label={item.label} value={item.value} textColor={Colors.myGold} Color={Colors.myGold} /> //tried this
          ))
        }
      </Picker>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 
1. If you are using a component which has style as its props so you can use as `color={Colors.myColorGold}` . like suppose in

```
<MaterialIcon color={Colors.myColorGold} />
```

and if you want to add a color property in the styles object you do :

```
const proAppHeaderStyles=StyleSheet.create({
    hederStyle:{
        color:"#4f58ff",
      } 
})
```

2. suppose you want to change in

   `<Text style={styles.emphasized}> {alert.SensorType}</Text>`  just go to styles.emphasized object where its defined and add color or fontsize whatever you want to change. e.g

   emphasized:{
   color:'red'
   }

3.`this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPreferences')` is same as the below one. Only that the above one states in explicitly and below syntax will only work if you first destructure navigate. i.e 
`const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;` and after that use navigate as below

this.navigate('NotificationPreferences')

4. SO you have to apply styles as below

```
<RNPickerSelect
              placeholder={{
                label: 'Select a number or add another...',
                value: null,
                color: 'red',
              }}
              items={this.state.numbers}
              onValueChange={value => {
                this.setState({
                  favNumber: value,
                });
              }}
              style={{
                ...pickerSelectStyles,
                iconContainer: {
                  top: 20,
                  right: 10,
                },
                placeholder: {
                  color: 'purple',
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                },
              }}
              value={this.state.favNumber}
              Icon={() => {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                      borderTopWidth: 10,
                      borderTopColor: 'gray',
                      borderRightWidth: 10,
                      borderRightColor: 'transparent',
                      borderLeftWidth: 10,
                      borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
                      width: 0,
                      height: 0,
                    }}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
```

so basically inside the style object you need to pass placeholder object and then the style :

```
style={{
                ...pickerSelectStyles,
                iconContainer: {
                  top: 20,
                  right: 10,
                },
                placeholder: { // this is the part
                  color: 'purple',
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                },
              }}
```

Do check out this link : [example](https://snack.expo.io/@lfkwtz/react-native-picker-select)

ask me for doubts.